# Unable to use write_http collectd plugin

Tags: collectd

I am running collectd 5.4.2.788.gf87af5a, I have also tried using 5.4.1.

I am seeing the following in the logs:

```
May  8 00:50:01 ip_172_1_1_1 collectd[19559]: Filter subsystem: Built-in target `write': Dispatching value to all write plugins failed with status 2 (ENOENT). Most likely this means you didn't load any write plugins.
```

And I have write_http writing to localhost:9103 and netcat listening on that port.

```
nc -l 9103
```

My collectd.conf:

```
LoadPlugin write_http
<Plugin write_http>
        <URL "http://127.0.0.1:9103/collectd-post">
                Format "JSON"
                StoreRates false
        </URL>
</Plugin>
```

The message goes away if I enable rrdtool but regardless of rrdtool being enabled nothing is printed by netcat so write_http isn't sending any data to that socket.

## UPDATE 1 - 2015.05.08

write_http is shipping stats from the cpu plugin but not from my own python plugin. But the python plugin does write to rrdtool any ideas?

## UPDATE 2 - 2015.05.08

Once I verified that write_http was working just not with my python plugin I found the culprit here: https://github.com/collectd/collectd/issues/716 using the meta data workaround resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I verified that write_http was working just not with my python plugin I found the culprit here: https://github.com/collectd/collectd/issues/716 using the meta data workaround resolved the issue.